# is it possible to use OpenGL for drawing in WinCE?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, opengl

For drawing graphics on WinCE emulator in visual studio 2008, currently i am trying to use GDI in VC++.
is it possible to use OpenGL for drawing on WinCE platform ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

However, OpenGL ES is doable.  You can use [Vincent](http://www.vincent3d.com/software/ogles1/ogles1.html) if your device doesn't have hardware support.